# Communication issue between vue js and spring boot under docker compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker, vue.js, nginx, docker-compose

I am struggeling with the following issue.
I have two apps, one is written in Vue and is my front end, the second is my backend written in spring boot.
I use a nginx as a reverse proxy and to manage HTTPs for me.

All of this is run with a docker compose file.

I am able to reach my front page but I try to fetch backend's data from the UI I got a an error.
[image]

I tried to remove the protection in firefox but I get another error:

[image]

However when curling the backend api using curl it is workign fine.

To summuraize:

- Display UI -> OK
- API call from host -> OK
- API call front front end inside docker -> KO

Here is the compose file:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.21.3-alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./cert.pem:/etc/nginx/cert.pem:ro
      - ./key.pem:/etc/nginx/key.pem:ro
      - ./api_proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/api_proxy.conf:ro
    networks:
      - backnet
  mysql:
    env_file: ./.env
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - ${MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT}:${MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT}
    volumes:
      - 'mysql_data:/bitnami/mysql/data'
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_USER=$MYSQLDB_USER
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQLDB_DATABASE
    healthcheck:
      test: [ 'CMD', '/opt/bitnami/scripts/mysql/healthcheck.sh' ]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 6
    networks:
      - backnet
  auth:
    env_file: ./.env
    container_name: $KEYCLOAK_CONTAINER_NAME
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_started
    image: jboss/keycloak:16.1.1
    ports:
      - ${KEYCLOAK_LOCAL_PORT}:${KEYCLOAK_DOCKER_PORT}
    environment:
      - DB_VENDOR=mysql
      - DB_DATABASE=$MYSQLDB_DATABASE
      - DB_USER=$MYSQLDB_USER
      - DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
    networks:
      - backnet
  backend:
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://localhost:6868/actuator/health  || exit 1
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 6
    env_file: ./.env
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_started
    restart: on-failure
    build:
      context: ../backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update",
        "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:mysql://mysql:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT/$MYSQLDB_DATABASE?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false",
        "spring.datasource.username" : "$MYSQLDB_USER",
        "spring.datasource.password" : "$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD",
        "spring.datasource.driver-class-name" : "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
        "spring.jpa.database-platform" : "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect",
        "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" : "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"
        }'
    expose:
      - ${SPRING_DOCKER_PORT}
    networks:
      - backnet
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ../frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - ${VUE_DOCKER_PORT}
    networks:
      - backnet
volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local
networks:
  backnet:
```

Nginx conf:

```
events { }

http {

  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default upgrade;
      ''      close;
    }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    return 301 https://localhost$request_uri;
         }

   server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/key.pem;

    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /dev/stderr warn;

    location / {
            include /etc/nginx/api_proxy.conf;
            proxy_pass http://frontend:8080/;
       }

    location /ads {
          include /etc/nginx/api_proxy.conf;
          proxy_pass http://frontend:8080/;
      }

    location /back {
       rewrite ^/back(.*)$ $1 break;
       include /etc/nginx/api_proxy.conf;
       proxy_pass http://backend:8081/;
    }

   }
}
```

Thx for any help.